# PHP MySQL Multiple File Upload

Tags: php, mysql, multiple-file-upload

I want to make multiple image upload in a one row but it creates two row, one is exactly that I want but the other one is null. Why it creates two row?

```
<?php
        $dir="img";
        $imgList = array();
        $files_count=count($_FILES['files']['name']);
        for($i=0;$i<$files_count;$i++){
        if(!empty($_FILES['files']['name'][$i]))
            {
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$i],$dir."/".$_FILES['files']['name'][$i]);
            $file_name = $_FILES['files']['name'][$i];
            array_push($imgList,$file_name);
            }                   
        }
        $imgs = implode(",",$imgList);
        mysqli_query($connect,"insert into episodes (Id,images) values ('','$imgs')");
?>
```

Comment: Image path with comma separated is bad practice. Now point is where is your HTML code. HTML and PHP files are same file? If yes then you need to use if condition for `POST` action.

Comment: My HTML and PHP files were in the same file, when I add if condition for POST, the null row is gone :) Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code :

```
<?php
    if(isset($_FILES['files'])) {
        $dir="img";
        $imgList = array();
        $files_count=count($_FILES['files']['name']);
        for($i=0;$i<$files_count;$i++){
        if(!empty($_FILES['files']['name'][$i]))
            {
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$i],$dir."/".$_FILES['files']['name'][$i]);
            $file_name = $_FILES['files']['name'][$i];
            array_push($imgList,$file_name);
            }                   
        }
        $imgs = implode(",",$imgList);
        mysqli_query($connect,"insert into episodes (Id,images) values ('','$imgs')");
 }
?>
```

You just need to check if file is set or not.